# Transaction check error installing local rpms

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I try to install two springBoot module with rpm, this is the error I get:

```
  file /path/config/application.yaml from install of master-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.noarch conflicts with file from package worker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.noarch
  file /path/config/log4j2.xml from install of master-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.noarch conflicts with file from package worker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.noarch
```

Can somebody explain why this is a problem and what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that both packages `master-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and `worker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` try to deploy same file (`application.yaml` and `log4j2.xml`) into same directory (`/path/config`).

In RPM (and possibly any other packaging system) no package can overwrite a file owned by other package.

To resolve the problem you can:

- add component name to the deployment path (say `/path/master/config` or `/path/worker/config`) so that each component has it's own set of deployed files.
- if you intend to share configuration between components and have them both use same config file, factor the configuration into a third package (e.g. `config-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`)

Comment: And they both had the same rpminstalldir